# cURL: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'GET' BASH script

Tags: bash, curl, web-crawler

I am having a problem with my bash script. It is producing an error of

curl (6) couldn't resolve host

What have I done wrong?

The following is my bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
(set -o igncr) 2>/dev/null && set -o igncr; # this comment is needed

CookieFileName=cookies.txt

TEST="curl -k --cookie  $CookieFileName --cookie-jar $CookieFileName POST -F "passUID=xxx&passUCD=xxx" https://wp1.coned.com/retailaccess/default.asp"

echo $TEST

RESPONSE=`$TEST`
echo $RESPONSE
```

Comment: does ping to wp1.coned.com have respone from your server ?

Comment: When `$TEST` is unquoted in the command substitution, the ampersand for your `-F` option is treated as the background operator, so `curl` doesn't see the host name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o igncr

CookieFileName='cookies.txt'

curl -k \
    --cookie "$CookieFileName" \
    --cookie-jar "$CookieFileName" \
    --data "passUID=xxx&passUCD=xxx" \
    "https://wp1.coned.com/retailaccess/default.asp" # POST request
```

If you need to load another page after that, simply chains `cURL` commands with the previous line :

```
curl -k \
    --cookie "$CookieFileName" \
    --cookie-jar "$CookieFileName" \
    "https://wp1.coned.com/retailaccess/another_page.asp" # GET request
```

### Note

Command Substitution: The `$(foo bar)` causes the command 'foo' to be executed with the argument 'bar' and `$(..)` will be replaced by the *output*. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Thank you that did assist.  It worked 1 time though and now I am getting <h1>Object Moved<\h1>This object may be found <a HREF="error.asp">here</a>

Comment: last question when I run the below code it page does not change.  If you review there should be a piece called Account Summary but it does not seem to show up on the post of the click.    TEST=$(curl -k --cookie "$CookieFileName" --cookie-jar "$CookieFileName" -d "ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_1bb6dc86_55ab_4ea9_a4db_4747922a8202$ctl00$RequestOption=1" "https://www.comed.com/customer-service/rates-pricing/customer-choice/Pages/usage-data.aspx"

Comment: Where does "ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_1bb6dc86_55ab_4ea9_a4db_4747922a8202$ctl00" comes from ? Sounds like a cookie ! `-d` or `--data` switch need `key=value` joined by `&`, not cookie. Thanks to read the doc : http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_1bb6dc86_55ab_4ea9_a4db_4747922a8202$ctl00 is the name of the radio button that gets clicked to refresh the page and additional items pop up after refresh.

Comment: It does not seem to be holding the cookie session because when I try to get the second page, it has a timeout on the page.  I checked the cookie file and it seems to be changing correctly and updating.  The file is one vertical line.  Does that matter?